Helfgott's Results on Proving the Ternary Goldbach Conjecture
Premise
I was looking over the paper and results from Helfgott's work in solving the weak Goldbach conjecture (aka three-prime conjecture or Ternary Goldbach conjecture). The paper itself is a lot to read through, but I was mostly interested in the results. At the end, it describes the lower bound for sufficiently large numbers (https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eharald.helfgott/anglais/book.html).
Question
Is the paper stating for all odd numbers $N$ where $10^{27} \leq N$, the number of ways to write the number $N$ as the sum of three odd primes is larger than $0.0002443 N^2$?
Edit
After doing more research, I am not certain that makes sense or if it was read correctly and most likely is derived from the work discussing the major or minor arc bounds. Therein, I did find this work (https://www.imj-prg.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/prix/helfgott2014.pdf).
I believe it is saying that the number of ways to write a sufficiently large odd number $N$ as the sum of three odd primes is asymptotically proportional to $\frac{N^2}{log(N)^3}$?

The number of ways to write $N$ as a sum of three integers from $0$ to $N$ is $\sim N^2$. If there were more than $CN^2$ - for some constant $C>0$ - triples of primes among those $\sim N^2$ triples of integers there would be at least $CN$ primes up to $N$ for all large enough $N$, which is false. The other estimate follows from the Cramér model for the distribution of primes, i guess that is what Helfgott got.
